# "likewise something, ..." grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

is the sentence below grammatically correct? don't mind the programming lingo.

Likewise the regular methods, we can use async and await keywords in the lambda expressions to take advantage of asynchronous operations.

is it valid to use "likewise" like this?

Comment: No, sorry. Please look up the term in a dictionary before posting. Please punctuate and use caps properly. Thank you.

Comment: @Lambie I checked the dictionaries, and in all of the examples, "likewise" is followed with a comma. I'm asking whether this particular sentence structure is valid. I saw the sentence in Microsoft documentation.

Comment: Why is it that people are so willing to reject answering questions? What I'm asking is very clear.

Comment: Likewise means *also*. He said he would not go with her. Likewise, she said she would not go with him either. i.e. Also, she said she would not go with him.//Fyi, I don't make the rules around here. Just so you know. And please punctuate correctly. I'm not editing you because you need to do it for yourself.